# Form sending me to the wrong controller despite correct URL in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form, nested-routes

I have the following routes defined:

*App/config/routes.rb*

```
resources :pools do
  resources :match_predictions, path: "predictions", as: "predictions", only:[:index, :create, :update]
  post "predictions/season" => "season_predictions#create"
  patch "predictions/season" => "season_predictions#update"
  put "predictions/season" => "season_predictions#update
end
```

Which result in the following paths/Url/controller#action (omitting pool resources routes for simplicity):

```
          pool_predictions GET    /pools/:pool_id/predictions(.:format)                                                    match_predictions#index
                           POST   /pools/:pool_id/predictions(.:format)                                                    match_predictions#create
           pool_prediction PATCH  /pools/:pool_id/predictions/:id(.:format)                                                match_predictions#update
                           PUT    /pools/:pool_id/predictions/:id(.:format)                                                match_predictions#update
   pool_predictions_season POST   /pools/:pool_id/predictions/season(.:format)                                             season_predictions#create
                           PATCH  /pools/:pool_id/predictions/season(.:format)                                             season_predictions#update
                           PUT    /pools/:pool_id/predictions/season(.:format)                                             season_predictions#update
```

**As context:** I have three models Pool, MatchPrediction, SeasonPrediction. Each @pool is a sports tipping competition that has_many @match_predictions and has_one @season_prediction. The key view in my app is where the user posts/updates his predictions. As most of it is @match_predictions, I'm using match_predictions#index & match_predictions/index.html.erb to control/display this view. This view is accessed via:

```
/pool/:pool_id/predictions
```

**The problem:** I have a form to create/update @season_prediction that lives within the realms of the match_predictions resource. In order to preserve error messages, in the event of objects failing to be saved, I'm rendering `match_predictions/index.html.erb` after failure of the update/create actions at the season_predictions_controller. This works well with the default routes, say if I do:

```
resources :pools do
  resources :match_predictions, path: "predictions", as: "predictions", only:[:index, :create, :update]
  resources :season_predictions
end
```

This has, however, the unintended consequence of modifying the location path to something like:

```
/pool/:pool_id/season_predictions/:id
```

I think this can be confusing for the user as he is still in the same view while the URL has changed drastically. Plus the :id at the end of the URL doesn't make any sense as the user can only have one season prediction per pool.
Hence with this approach I wanted to achieve

1. The URL after action failure must be as similar as possible to the original `/pool/:pool_id/match_predictions`.
2. Remove the :id at the end of the URL, that belongs to the @season_prediction.
3. Use the same form to either create or update @season_prediction depending if I'm serving a new instance or a
   previously  saved instance form the controller.

So far I've a form like:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@pool, @season_prediction], url: pool_predictions_season_path) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :champion %>
    <%= f.input :second_place %>
    <%= f.input :third_place %>
    <%= f.input :last_place %>
    <%= f.association :pool_participant %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Although the rendered HTML form sets the correct action path to: `action="/pools/1/predictions/season"` upon submission it sends the request to match_predictions#update which I don't get exactly why as there's no involvement of the that controller.

Could you please help me understand why and achieve the expected outcome?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that when setting routes with a slash, such as the ones between 'predictions' and 'seasons' in the following routes:

```
  post "predictions/season" => "season_predictions#create"
  patch "predictions/season" => "season_predictions#update"
  put "predictions/season" => "season_predictions#update
```

It was interfering with Rails in such way that the season_prediction controller was ignored and the match_predictions controller was reached given the customisation of the url method `as: "predictions"` which coincide purposefully.

```
resources :match_predictions, path: "predictions", as: "predictions", only:[:index, :create, :update]
```

I ended up getting rid of the slash and setting the season_prediction routes as the one below:

```
put "predictionss" => "season_predictions#update"
```

Yes with double 's' at the end to differentiate from the match predictions controller routes. This doesn't feel like best practice at all. It may confuse other people when reading the code but at least the user will hardly notice the change.